# How to dynamically add a new look and feel?

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel

I want to make sure that the user himself could add L & F.
But how to do this I do not understand.
it is even possible?

Comment: even I do not understand , your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right then it is pretty straight forward really. Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html. There is even a demo app that lets you change the L&F on the fly.

The important class doing most of the work is [UIManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to understand

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to update all components shown in the frame

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```